# get input from multiple threads and upload file with fixed size to S3

Tags: java, multithreading

I write a thread safe class to get input from multiple threads and upload the result to S3 once it runs up to a fixed size.

**S3Exporter class**

```
// this class is thread safe.
public class S3Exporter {
    private static final int BUFFER_PADDING = 1000;
    private final int targetSize;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream buf;
    private volatile boolean started;

    public S3Exporter(final int targetSize) {
        buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(targetSize + BUFFER_PADDING);
        this.targetSize = targetSize;
        started = false;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        started = true;
    }

    public synchronized void end() {
        started = false;
        flush();
    }

    public synchronized void export(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkState(started, "Not started!");
        buf.write(b, buf.size(), b.length);
        flushIfNeeded();
    }

    private void flushIfNeeded() {
        if (buf.size() >= targetSize) {
            flush();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void flush() {
        if (buf.size() > 0) {
            // upload buf to s3, it's a time-consuming operation
            buf.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

The client calls export method to pass data and if exception is thrown the client will pass that data later.
To avoid losing data when restarting the application, I add a shutdown hook when creating S3Exporter object:

```
    S3Exporter exporter = new S3Exporter(10000);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> exporter.end()));
```

My concern is the class is not scalable, I mean it could become bottleneck of the system when data are getting more. I could figure out 2 ways to improve the situation:

> 1. do the time-consuming upload operation asynchronously: use an executor to upload and call ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination() in the shutdown hook.
> 2. just put data to a LinkedBlockingQueue in export method and use multiple threads to handle it.( This way is more scalable than the first per my understanding)

Then I need to do more work in the shutdown hook thread to make sure not losing the accepted data and it's not a good idea as I know. I'll take the risk of losing data when restarting the application, which is the last thing I wanna see.

**My question**

> 1. Is my concern about the scalability a really problem?( To make the question less stupid, let's say the data size is a few bytes and TPS to call export method is 500)
> 2. If the answer to the 1st question is yes, what about my improvements, are they right? How to do the cleanup work to avoid losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Scalability depends on requirements, constraints, desired service level, personal preferences, expected users growth rate, and especially money: given infinite resources, every piece of software can be scaled. You didn't mention any, so I guess you don't have any actual figure. In this phase, as a programmer, your job is to make a **correct** program that uses a **predictable** amount of resources.

Your program seems correct, and most of your assumptions are correct, too. However I suggest to immediately store chunks to some local persistent database (or the raw filesystem) and have a periodic job, run in a separate thread, that upload group of chunks to S3, and remove any shutdown hooks (you can use Camel for the boring parts). This is because such hooks are unreliable and should only be used as last resources for quick and optional cleanup (optional in the sense that you must be prepared that the cleanup could not have been run properly until the end).

Using a file instead of memory, your data can survive fatal errors and the working memory required by your application is almost independent on the load: there's an irrelevant amount of extra CPU and some disk I/O that is way cheaper then memory.